# Can another person access my sqlite Data?

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite, android-studio

I was using firebase till now and a friend recommended me to use Sqlite.. I was wondering if i setup a quiz in my app and it stores the data to my phone's sqlite... can others get access to it if my internet connection is fine? i used to use firebase for such a purpose but was wondering if sqlite can perform this function

Comment: Local SQLite databases cannot be read just by using the data connection. Just remember that a SQLite database is local, though! The user experience will be different than using Firebase, that is an online service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, others can get access to the data stored in that SQLite database. Here are just a couple of scenarios:

- You store the SQLite database on external storage (e.g. a microSD card) and someone gets access to that microSD card. (E.g. you leave your phone unattended and someone removes the card.)
- Someone gains physical access to your phone. (E.g. you turn it in for repairs without wiping the storage first.)
- You store backups of your phone on your computer and someone gains access to those backups.
- You store backups of your phone on an USB key and lose that USB key.
- There is a security bug in Android that allows remote access to the phone's storage.
- There is a security bug in the quiz app that allows remote access to app's storage.

These are just some of the ways in which someone can get access to that database.

Answer (score 0):

Sqlite data is stored in your phone's storage (doesn't require internet) whereas firebase is cloud storage (requires internet). In both cases no one can see your data. If you are only making a quiz app i would recommend sqlite database as it will store the data in user's phone.

Answer (score 0):

Sqlite database stored in internal storage of your app, so only your app can access to it. But if device have root, there are possibility to extract database.

Answer (score 0):

Sqlite database was highly preferable if you are making a quiz app. Since it stores the data in user's device,I'm afraid that data can't be shared with other devices (until shared physically). And that won't be efficient for an application. I would prefer using parse server, for sharing those data over the internet with other devices.